# Como posso executar um script automaticamente na criação de um container?

Tags: docker

Estou com a seguinte necessidade: ao criar um novo container gostaria de automaticamente executar o script `/usr/local/bin/start` que se encontra dentro da imagem, este script basicamente verifica se a variável **TIPO_AMBIENTE** é igual a **prod**, se sim altera 2 parâmetros de arquivos.

**Obs**: inicialmente gostaria de rodar esse script só na criação do container, porém, não tem problema caso a única alternativa seja executa-lo sempre que o container for iniciado.

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

MAINTAINER Fabio J L Ferreira <fabiojaniolima@gmail.com>

# Instala e configura componentes essenciais
RUN apt-get update && \
    a2enmod rewrite && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends unzip git && \
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin/ --filename=composer; \
    echo "America/Sao_Paulo" > /etc/timezone; \
    \
    # Configura componentes do Apache e PHP
    { \
        echo '<VirtualHost *:80>'; \
        echo '\tServerAdmin webmaster@localhost'; \
        echo '\tDocumentRoot /var/www'; \
        echo; \
        echo '\tErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log'; \
        echo '\tCustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined'; \
        echo; \
        echo '\t<Directory /var/www>'; \
        echo '\t\tOptions Indexes FollowSymLinks'; \
        echo '\t\tAllowOverride None'; \
        echo '\t\tRequire all granted'; \
        echo '\t</Directory>'; \
        echo '</VirtualHost>'; \
    } | tee /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf; \
    docker-php-source extract; \
    cp /usr/src/php/php.ini-development /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini; \
    sed -i 's/upload_max_filesize = 2M/upload_max_filesize = 50M/' /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini; \
    docker-php-source delete

# Aqui instalamos algumas extensões comumente utilizadas
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libjpeg-dev libpng-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ && \
    docker-php-ext-install gd; \
    \
    # Instala a extensão PHP "exif" => http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.exif.php
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libexif-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-install exif; \
    \
    # Instala as extensões PHP "mysqli pdo_mysql pgsql pdo_pgsql"
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libpq-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql && \
    docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo_mysql pgsql pdo_pgsql

# Limpa repositório local
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /var/www

EXPOSE 80

COPY start /usr/local/bin/
```

Como poderia fazer isso? Após resolver este problema, preciso verificar se passando essa variável na criação do container terei o efeito esperado.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isso usando o comando [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint). Com ele, você especifica um comando para executar quando o container iniciar, assim não precisa sempre especificar o comando na linha de comando conforme sugerido em outra resposta.

Você disse que prefere um método que execute apenas na criação, e não em toda execução. Mas é relativamente simples colocar uma regra no script para verificar se ele já foi executado ou não. Você pode usar um arquivo de configuração, por exemplo, para verificar isso.

Concordo que seria legal uma solução nativa, mas isso é objeto de [muito debate na comunidade docker](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1809). Foi implementado o [`docker-compose events`](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/2392), permitindo que você crie um script [como esse](https://gist.github.com/dnephin/c56b479810f863527e90), mas eu não tenho certeza em como isso ajudaria a fazer o que pretende.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder rodar qualquer comando depois que o container for criado basta adiciona-lo depois do nome da imagem:

```
docker container run nome-da-imagem comando-aqui
```

Podes tambem adicionar mais opcoes ao comando acima. Exemplo usando a distribuicao Alpine Linux:

```
$ docker container run -e TIPO_AMBIENTE=prod alpine env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=8483090bf7ec
TIPO_AMBIENTE=prod
HOME=/root
```

Entao, por exemplo, pra rodar o seu script:

```
docker container run -e TIPO_AMBIENTE=prod sua-imagem /usr/local/bin/start
```

Comment: não teria como incluir isso em forma de script no Dockerfile, para ser executado na criação do container, ou seja, ao "iniciar" a imagem?

Comment: Ah, sim. Se voce quiser que sempre execute isso e seja imbutido na imagem, basta usar o CMD no final do Dockerfile. Assim, sempre que a imagem for usada pra gerar um container, no final o comando vai rodar dentro do container. Por exemplo, no final do Dockerfile: `CMD ["/usr/local/bin/start"]`

Comment: Cheguei a fazer algo assim, porém, fiquei impossibilitado de rodar o container com a opção -d

Comment: @FábioJânio talvez seja porque voce precisa usar o tini pra rodar o script. https://github.com/krallin/tini